# Deleting element in Binary Search Tree (BST)

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree, graph-algorithm

I have difficulties with deleting element from BST. This code is based on algorithm from Cormen's book. Here are two functions needed to delete element:

```
el *TreeSuccessor(el *x)
{
    el *y;
    if (x->right != NULL){
        return TreeMinimum(x->right);
    }
    y= x->p;

    while (y != NULL && x == y->right){
        x = y;
        y = y->p;
    }
    return y;
}


void TreeDelete (el* &root, el *z, el* &y)
{
    el *x;
    if (z->left == NULL || z->right == NULL){
        y=z;
    }
    else{
        y=TreeSuccessor(z);
    }

    if(y->left != NULL){
        x = y->left;
    }
    else{
        x = y->right;
    }

    if (x!=NULL){
        x->p = y->p;
    }

    if (y->p == NULL){
       root=x;
    }
    else if (y == y->p->left){
       y->p->left = x;
    }
    else{
       y->p->right = x;
    }


    if (y!=z){
       z->indeks = y->indeks;
       strcpy(z->name,y->name);
       strcpy(z->surname,y->surname);
    }
}
```

And here is a code responsible for calling function in `int main()`:

```
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        File>>keyToSearch;
        searchedLeave=TreeSearch(root,keyToSearch);

        TreeDelete(root,searchedLeave,leaveToDelete);
        delete leaveToDelete;
    }
```

Here is a complete program http://pastebin.com/FgvWPzm9

**Program crashes during deletion.**

Comment: Did you have a question  ?

Comment: When i have bst with for example 10000 elements, my algorithm crashes on 1012th element during deleting elements.

Comment: Can you post the error message you receive ? You should also tag the language you are using because more people will see this post.

Comment: In fact my algorithm delete bad element for 20 elements from first 1012 elements, and then application in console crashes. I think that it could be a problem with root, but i'm not sure.

Comment: I have Cormen's book and I far as I can see that's a correct implementation of his algorithm. I think you're going to have to post a complete program, it's possible your error is somewhere else.

Comment: I added code of complete program.

Comment: Ok, now i have more specified question, my application crashes, when root is deleted. I'm not sure, if my reference to root is good. When i try to delete root of BST, program crashes.

Comment: @luke I ran your code but I'm not going to create a file of 10000 names, so I ran it with just 3. With only 3 I didn't see any problems. I think the most likely explanation for the bugs that you see is that you have names in your file that are more than 11 characters long. You have declared the name and surname to be only 12 characters big, which means your names and surnames must be 11 characters or less. I would try increasing the size of those arrays to see if that helps.

Comment: Worked fine for me too, deleting root and all. You might do a `if(searchedElement == NULL) continue;` for safety in between the search and delete (immediately after the search actually) to catch anything where a delete is attempted on a non-existent element.